# Change Kendo Pie Chart white background

Tags: angular, path, kendo-chart

Im working angular, and Im using kendo pie chart.

[image: original]

I want to change the white background of the charts, I tried to give the background color different color than white (default) but no way.

because at run time it is path, and I can change the color by changing the fill property in element.style.

[image: run time]

But in my css, I tried a lot to change it, it didnt work. and the following style has changed it, but it
fill it, so I can't see the chart at all.

```
  :host ::ng-deep .k-chart-surface svg {
    path{
    //background-color: rgba(119, 47, 47, 0.5);
    fill: #ccc;

    }
```

[image: fill from scss]

Answer (score 1):

Set the `chartArea` value:

```
chartArea: {
    background: "transparent"   // or "#F7F7F7",  
},
```

See: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/pie-charts/index